# error readlink: missing operand

Tags: command-line, apt, lubuntu, dpkg

I used this command: `sudo apt-get remove --purge opera-stable` and now I can't use my terminal.

```
readlink: missing operand
Try 'readlink --help' for more information.
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke 'stat -c %Z $(readlink -f $(which opera)) > /tmp/opera.timestamp'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: Please run `sudo grep -irE "readlink.*opera" /var/lib/dpkg/` and add its output to the question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1378416/edit) it.

Comment: nothing happens after entering that command

Comment: What do you have for `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ?

Comment: I have managed to fix it, thanks, it was dpkg error, and retain broken packages

Comment: If problem is fixed, please answer the question by yourself to help other users solve similar problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)